# How do I style the borders of a formik error field?

Tags: css, formik

I know how to style it with regular form inputs/selects/etc, but I have switched from using those to Formik Field, and the above doesn't work the same way.

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    example: ''
  }}
  validate={(values) => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.example) errors.example = 'Required';

    return errors;

  }}
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  render={formProps => {
    return (
      <Form>
        <Field type='text' name='example' />
        <ErrorMessage name='example' />
      </Form>
    )
  }} />
```

So how would I change the border of the input from whatever it is normally to red if it is empty on submit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution

You can style `Field` and `ErrorMessage` components provided by `Formik` just like you would style any other component in react. I created a working demo for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-formik-field-error-styles

Have a look. Continue reading for explanation.

### Explanation

The simplest way would be to use `style` prop:

```js
function getStyles(errors, fieldName) {
  if (getIn(errors, fieldName)) {
    return {
      border: '1px solid red'
    }
  }
}

...

<Field style={getStyles(formProps.errors, 'example')} type='text' name='example' />

...
```

However, if you need manageable customizations, I would recommend you create a custom component. `Field` provides you with a `component` prop to which you can assign your own custom component like `CustomInput` or something like so:

```js
function getStyles(errors, fieldName) {
  if (getIn(errors, fieldName)) {
    return {
      border: '1px solid red'
    }
  }
}

function CustomInput({ field, form: { errors } }) {

  return <div>
    <input {...field} style={getStyles(errors, field.name)} />
    <ErrorMessage name={field.name} />
  </div>
}

...

<Field component={CustomInput} type="text" name="example" />

...
```

Comment: When i try your technique for `ErrorMessage` component using `<ErrorMessage name="propertyName" style={{ color: 'red'}}/>`, it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: `<ErrorMessage />` component supports `component` and `render` props as well. So you can do something like `<ErrorMessage render={message => <div style={{color: 'red'}}>{message}</div>} />`. That way you can style the error based on message type if something like that is required.

Comment: This applies the style as soon as an error appear during input, but error messages are shown on blur I believe, so, they are not in sync.

Comment: There is problem in this solution. If you leave one field as blank, **both** of them get the red border, as if you touched both.

Answer (score 6):

When i try the technique suggested in the accepted answer for `ErrorMessage` component using

```
<ErrorMessage name="propertyName" style={{ color: 'red'}}/>
```

it didn't work for me. It worked when i enclosed it inside another container though.

```
<div style={{ color: 'red'}}>
     <ErrorMessage name="propertyName" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the workaround that works for styling error fields (e.g. borders) is given here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66395574/1005607

Pretty astonishing that Formik doesn't provide this functionality out of the box, and you have to extend `<Field>` with custom code.

But in general, you're not supposed to use Formik's own `<Field>` component. Instead you should wire Formik to a component library like **Material UI** or **React-Bootstrap** which exposes `isInvalid={..}` or `error={..}` props on its components. That will allow you to style your controls properly. Here's an example of how to wire Formik to React-Bootstrap: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries If you type into a control, you'll see how its style changes depending on errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've built a Component using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation-libraries) based on [@gene b. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66677881/1677209)

It gets the `meta` field from the `useField` hook  and passes eventual errors to the `isInvalid` prop:

`isInvalid={meta.touched && meta.error}`

Full component for text input:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useField } from 'formik';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export default function TextInput (props) {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
      <Form.Group controlId={props.name}>
        <Form.Label>{props.label}</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name={props.name}
          isInvalid={meta.touched && meta.error}
          {...field}
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
          {meta.error}
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
      </Form.Group>
  );
};
```

Usage

```
import { Form } from 'formik';
import TextInput from './textInput';
<Form>
  <TextInput name="username" label="Username"/>
</Form>
```

It's worth mention that exists also the `isValid` prop that works exactly the opposite way, adding green flag on valid fields.