# Change style of existing input fields whenever error occurs in React Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, css-modules

In my React Form which I had created using React Formik library, I want to change the style  of my input element's border color to ***1px solid red*** whenever there is an error.

But as we know react formik renders a new error component using ErrorMessage whenever it founds a new validation error so basically how do we make a change to our ***existing input field*** colour when error occurs?

CSS :

```
.formGroup input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.formGroup input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.formGroup button {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.error {
  color: red;
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classes from "./P.module.css";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
const initialValues = {
  company_name: "",
  company_profile: "The Opinia is news and media company",
  location: "",
  phone_number: "",
  email: "",
  gst: "",
};

const onSubmit = (values) => {
  console.log("Form Data: ", values);
};

// for validation
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  company_name: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  company_profile: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  location: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  email: Yup.string().required("Required").email("Invalid email format"),
  phone_number: Yup.number().required("Required"),
  gst: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});
export default function Projects2(props) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.main}>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        <Form className={classes.form}>
          <div className={`${classes.formGroup}`}>
            <label htmlFor="company_name">Company Name</label>
            <Field type="text" id="company_name" name="company_name" />
            <ErrorMessage name="company_name" component={TextError} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <label htmlFor="company_profile">Company Profile</label>
            <Field type="text" id="company_profile" name="company_profile" />
            <ErrorMessage name="company_profile" component={TextError} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <label htmlFor="location">Location</label>
            <Field type="text" id="location" name="location" />
            <ErrorMessage name="location" component={TextError} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <label htmlFor="phone_number">Phone</label>
            <Field type="number" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" />
            <ErrorMessage name="phone_number" component={TextError} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            <ErrorMessage name="email" component={TextError} />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <label htmlFor="gst">GST Number</label>
            <Field type="text" id="gst" name="gst" />
            <ErrorMessage name="gst" component={TextError} />
          </div>

          <div className={classes.formGroup}>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export function TextError(props) {
  return <div className={classes.error}>{props.children}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react formik fastfields in order to perform valdiation through the react js form

Answer (score 6):

As of now there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. You can render a custom children for `<Field>` to achieve this. Example:

```js
<Field type="text" name="firstName">
  { ({ 
       field, 
       meta: { touched, error } 
    }) => <input className={ touched && error ? "invalid" : "" } { ...field } />
  }
</Field>
```

Then in css

```css
input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Update: Here is links to documentation: The `field` input has the shape of [FieldInputProps](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldinputpropsvalue) and `meta` is a [FieldMetaProps](https://formik.org/docs/api/useField#fieldmetapropsvalue)

**However, you're supposed to use a special control library, like React-Bootstrap or Materia-UI, which facilitates this -- you're not supposed to use Formik directly for this.** Formik is just for gathering/submitting data, not for detailed form elements.

Comment: `'fields' is not defined` for this example.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this! I had a typo. In expanded `fields` is supposed to be `field`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Works now, thanks. Pretty shocking that Formik doesn't let you style error fields, isn't it? Do you know why <Field> doesn't maintain its error status? Why wouldn't it just have an `errorStyle` or `style` attribute or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required result via CSS

Let's use the following form field as an example:

```
<div>
    <label className={"formLabel"} htmlFor="phoneNumber">
        Phone number
    </label>
    <ErrorMessage className={"formError"} name="phoneNumber" component={'span'} />
    <Field className={"formInput"} name="phoneNumber" />
</div>
```

Until an error occurs - Formik will not render the `<ErrorMessage />` component

Considering the behavior described above - we can render an `<ErrorMessage />` component before the `<Field />` component, and use CSS class for ErrorMessage that will change styles of input when an error occurs

```
.formError + input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```